# CursorAdapter View recycling behavior

Tags: android, performance, android-cursoradapter, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android development, so my concern may be fundamentally flawed. I've searched for details about this and haven't found much.

My custom `CursorAdapter` creates a new `View` object for each line item in my `Cursor`, rather than creating `View` objects based on the number of visible list items + 2*columns for scrolling support and reusing.

It appears to derive from the implemented [getView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29) method in the `CursorAdapter`. The method is called with a null View parameter for each line item in the `Cursor` object, forcing `newView()` to be called each time.

Is this normal behavior? The `CursorAdapter` leaves a large memory footprint, to the extent of causing an OOM exception.

Here's the full adapter:

```
public class MovieCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    private final String LOG_TAG = MovieCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovieCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags){
        super(context,cursor,flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_image_view,parent,false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MoviesContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_POSTER_PATH));// TODO continue

        try {
            Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            Picasso.with(context).load(url).noFade().into(viewHolder.imageView);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error loading image:" +e.toString());
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.imageview_movies)
        ImageView imageView;

        ViewHolder(View view){
            ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        }
    }
}
```

GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity$MovieGridFragment">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_image_view_movie_width"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_image_view_movie_spacing"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

ImageView Items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think problem is mess with ViewHolder & View for return type of newView()

Comment: But once `newView()` is called, the adapter has already determined a new `View` is required. That seems too late to be the root cause.